# Trying to read a webpage with urllib and getting meta data

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm new to scraping sites, but here's what I've been able to put together so far:

```
page = urlopen(
    Request(
        https://www.example.com,
        data = None,
        headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
        }
     )
)

print(page.read())
```

After setting the User-Agent I no longer get a 405 error, but I don't get the actual webpage, just the metadata:

`b'<!DOCTYPEhtml>\n<html>\n\n\t\n\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\n\t\n\t\n\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\n<head>\n<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">\n<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />\n<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />\n<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />\n<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />\n<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />\n<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?Ref=/&amp;distil_RID=E302A72E-F80D-11E7-BB05-F067B31C80C1&amp;distil_TID=20180113030018" />\n<script type="text/javascript">\n\t(function(window){\n\t\ttry {\n\t\t\tif (typeof sessionStorage !== \'undefined\'){\n\t\t\t\tsessionStorage.setItem(\'distil_referrer\', document.referrer);\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t} catch (e){}\n\t})(window);\n</script>\n<script type="text/javascript" src="/cndnrlsttdstl.js" defer></script><style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#xwdaqqdutzds{display:none!important}</style></head>\n<body>\n<div id="distil_ident_block">&nbsp;</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n'`

Any idea how to pull the actual html that you'd see when inspecting the page?

Comment: the page contents may be loaded onto the page using javascript; if that's the case there are other libraries that can return the content after the js load.

Comment: what is your site?

Comment: Trying to scrape from www.realtor.ca. Makes sense that it's scraping before the js loads. Any suggestions on libraries to use?

Comment: You can probably do what you want with [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Try mechanize as well

Comment: scrapy with splash is also good option for dynamic websites

Comment: Success! I was able to use Selenium to open the webpage, but I was finding that the elements weren't loaded before I was pulling the html. All I had to do was use `time.sleep(10)` to wait for 10 seconds before pulling the html and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help everyone!